# How to compare 2 text input values?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to create a simple game where you have to answer the correct answer from a calculation.

I already have the function to generate random calculations, but i don't know how to compare it with the result which the user writted.

I tried to make the `if`, so when the user press the submit button, then the app will try to determine if that's the correct answer.

```js
var numArray = ["10/2", "5x5", "12-22", "5-6", "20-70"];
var question = document.getElementById("textQuestion");
var answer = document.getElementById("textAnswer");

function rollDice() {
  document.form[0].textQuestion.value = numArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * numArray.length)];
}

function equal() {
  var dif = document.forms[0].textQuestion.value
  if (dif != document.forms[0].textAnswer.value) {
    life--;
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="textview" id="textQuestion">
  <br>
  <textarea id="textAnswer" form="post" placeholder="Answer"></textarea>
</form>
<input type="button" name="start" onclick="">
```

Comment: RollDice function is wrong. That is not how you set an attribute value.

Comment: That's the only idea i had in mind to show a random item in an array.

Comment: Ok Cool. I have just changed your code a little to achieve exactly what you're looking for. Check my answer below. It will depend on you how you want to inform the user when they're matched or not but I've used an alert() just to notify. Run the Snippet and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.forms[0].textQuestion.value` looking for an element with `name=textQuestion`, which doesn't exist. Use `getElementById` instead or add `name` attribute  (needed to work with the input value on server-side).

```
function equal() {
    if (document.getElementById('textQuestion').value != document.getElementById('textAnswer').value) {
        life--; // life is undefined
    }
}

// don't forget to call `equal` and other functions.
```

Comment: uppercase 'I' of course... `getElementById`. You should find it out in 1 sec od googling, it's just typo...

Comment: This is just wrong. JavaScript will return an equation expression like "5x5" and not 25. so it will just keep breaking. You will need to evaluate the expression prior to comparing it to the answer. Us eval() function.

Answer (score 0):

There's more I would fix and add for what you're trying to achieve.

First of you need a *QA* mechanism to store both the question and the correct answer. An object literal seems perfect for that case: `{q: "", a:""}`.

You need to store the current dice number, so you can reuse it when needed (see `qa_curr` variable)

Than you could check the user trimmed answer equals the `QA.a`

Example:

```js
let life = 10,
  qa_curr = 0;
const EL = sel => document.querySelector(sel),
  el_question = EL("#question"),
  el_answer = EL("#answer"),
  el_check = EL("#check"),
  el_lives = EL("#lives"),
  qa = [{
    q: "Calculate 10 / 2", // Question
    a: "5", // Answer
  }, {
    q: "What's the result of 5 x 5",
    a: "25"
  }, {
    q: "5 - 6",
    a: "-1"
  }, {
    q: "Subtract 20 from 70",
    a: "-50"
  }];

function rollDice() {
  qa_curr = ~~(Math.random() * qa.length);
  el_question.textContent = qa[qa_curr].q;
  el_lives.textContent = life;
}

function checkAnswer() {
  const resp = el_answer.value.trim(),
    is_equal = qa[qa_curr].a === el_answer.value;
  let msg = "";

  if (resp === '') return alert('Enter your answer!'); 

  if (is_equal) {
    msg += `CORRECT! ${qa[qa_curr].q} equals ${resp}`;
    rollDice();
  } else {
    msg += `NOT CORRECT! ${qa[qa_curr].q} does not equals ${resp}`;
    life--;
  }
  if (life) {
    msg += `\nLives: ${life}`
  } else {
    msg += `\nGAME OVER. No more lifes left!`
  }
  // Show result msg
  el_answer.value = '';
  alert(msg);
}

el_check.addEventListener('click', checkAnswer);

// Start game
rollDice();
```

```html
<span id="question"></span><br>
<input id="answer" placeholder="Your answer">
<input id="check" type="button" value="Check"> (Lives:<span id="lives"></span>)
```

The above still misses a logic to not repeat questions, at least not insequence :) but hopefully this will give you a good start.

Comment: To be honest, this is what i was looking for, but i don't understand half of what's there. Thanks you for taking your time to answer my question and making more effort trying to help me tho!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you're looking for. I simply `alert(true || false )` based on match between the random and the user input. Check the Snippet for functionality and comment accordingly.

```js
var numArray = ["10/2", "5x5", "12-22", "5-6", "20-70"];
var questionElement = document.getElementById("textQuestion");
var answerElement = document.getElementById("textAnswer");

function rollDice() {
  var question = numArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * numArray.length)];
  questionElement.setAttribute("value", question);
}

//rolldice() so that the user can see the question to answer
rollDice();

function equal() 
{
  var dif = eval(questionElement.value); //get the random equation and evaluate the answer before comparing
  var answer = Number(answerElement.value); //get the answer from unser input
  var result = false; //set match to false initially
  if(dif === answer){
    result =  true; //if match confirmed return true
  }
  
  //alert the match result
  alert(result);
  
}

document.getElementById("start").addEventListener
(
  "click",
  function()
  {
    equal();
  }
);
```

```html
<input type="textview" id="textQuestion" value="">
<br>
<textarea id="textAnswer" form="post" placeholder="Answer"></textarea>

<input type="button" id="start" value="Start">
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks! Now i can figure out how to implement this with the app itself

Comment: @AlexFath Well Done. I hope everything works well. Mark as answer then if you were satisfied.